# Restructure Array in PHP to extact data

Tags: php, arrays

My current Array looks like the following which i'm trying to restructure to be able to exact data more efficiently

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  2022, 6, amex_direct, 99.991
    [1] =>  2022, 7, amex_direct, 99.984
    [2] =>  2022, 8, amex_direct, 99.98
    [3] =>  2022, 9, amex_direct, 99.986
    [4] =>  2022, 5, first_data, 99.995
    [5] =>  2022, 6, first_data, 99.995
    [6] =>  2022, 7, first_data, 99.982
    [7] =>  2022, 8, first_data, 99.996
    [8] =>  2022, 9, first_data, 99.995
    [9] =>  2022, 5, integrations, 99.994
    [10] =>  2022, 6, integrations, 99.988
    [11] =>  2022, 7, integrations, 99.882
    [12] =>  2022, 8, integrations, 99.991
    [13] =>  2022, 9, integrations, 99.959
    [14] =>  2022, 9, mastercard_direct, 100.0
    [15] =>  2022, 5, moneris, 99.99
    [16] =>  2022, 6, moneris, 99.985
    [17] =>  2022, 7, moneris, 99.997
    [18] =>  2022, 8, moneris, 99.97
    [19] =>  2022, 9, moneris, 99.993

    )
```

I'm looking to have it broken down easier as the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => [year] => 2022
       [month] => 6
       [name] => amex_direct
       [percent] => 99.991
[1] => [year] => 2022
       [month] => 6
       [name] => amex_direct
       [percent] => 99.984  
    .......
```

Comment: If you are parsing lines of a csv file, then use a native csv parsing function.  If you want those numeric values to be cast as integers or floats, then I'd likely use `sscanf()`.  Please put more effort into future questions to show what similar questions you found on Stack Overflow as well as your best failed coding attempt.  Always present your PHP array data as `var_export()` output so that contributors can instantly use it.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array, explode the elements and re-assign the value.

```
 $array = array( "2022, 6, amex_direct, 99.991", "2022, 7, amex_direct, 99.984" );
 $keys = array( 'year', 'month', 'name', 'percent' );
 foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
     $array[$key] = explode( ',', $val );
     $temp = array();
     for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $array[$key] ); $i++ ) {
         $temp[$keys[$i]] = $array[$key][$i];
     }
     $array[$key] = $temp;
 }
```